# Unable to find Blazor files in chrome debugable window at sources tab

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

So, i've been trying Blazor for a while and i've already used this functionality(debug on chrome) some time ago when i discovered it. But now i follow the steps(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0) to debug Blazor Wasm on the Browser but the Blazor files don't appear where they are supposed to for me to insert breakpoints.

Anyone knows how to solve this?
I have Visual Studio 2019 updated

Answer (score 0):

The solution i've found is to press again Shift+Alt+D in the new DEBUG window, which in turn will make appear another a new separator with only the debuger to interact with. And the so precious Blazor files on which we can put breakpoints.